# Why am I running out of memory when downloading multiple files in appcelerator mobile on Android

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I have asked this question also on the appcelerator forum, but as I find I often get better answers from you lovely people here on stackoverflow I am also asking it here just incase anyone can spread some light.

I have created a downloadQueue of urls and am using it to download files with the httpclient. Each file in the downloadQueue is is sent the the httpclient one at a time, with the next download being initiated only after the previous has been completed.
When I start the download, it seems to be working correctly and manages to download several files before it it simply freezes and I get an "out of memory" error in the DDMS error log.
I tried implementing suggestions found in other posts a sample of which are:

[http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/28911/httpclient-leaks-easily-or-can-we-have-a-close-method#answer-104241][1]

[http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/35041/large-file-download-on-mobile][2]

[http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120129/httpclient-and-setfile][3]

[http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/95521/httpclient---save-response-directly-to-file][4]

I tried all of the following:
- moving larger file downloads directly form the nativepath rather then simply saving to file in order to insure that tmp files are not kept longer then necessary.
using the undocument setFile method of the httpclient. (This stopped my code dead without any error message, and as it is undocumented I have no idea if it was ever implemented on android anyway)

-using a settimeout in httplient.onload after the file has been download to pause for 1 second before requesting the next file (I have no idea how this would help, but I am clutching a straws now)

Below is the relevant parts of my code (which is complete except for the GetFileUrls functions which I excluded for simplicity sake as all this function does is return an array of URLs).

Can anyone spot anything that might be causing my memory issue. Does anyone have any ideas as I have tried everthing I can think of? (HELP!)

```
var count = 0;
var downloadQueue = [];
var rootDir = Ti.Filesystem.getExternalStorageDirectory();

downloadQueue = GetFileUrls(); /* this function is not included in order to keep my post as short as possible, bu it returns an array of urls */
DownloadFile(downloadQueue[count]);

var downloader = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({timeout:10000});

downloader.onerror = function(){
    Ti.API.info(this.responseData);
}

downloader.onload = function(){
    SaveFile(this.folderName, this.fileName, this.responseData);
    count += 1;

    setTimeout( function(){ DownloadFile(); }, 1000);
}

function DownloadFile(){
    if (count < downloadQueue.length){
        var fileUrl = downloadQueue[count];
        var fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        downloader.fileName = fileName;
        downloader.folderName = rootDir;

        downloader.open('GET', fileUrl);
        downloader.send();
    }
}

function SaveFile(foldername, filename, response){  
    if (response.type == 1){
        var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(response.nativePath);
        var dest = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(foldername, filename);

        if (dest.exists()){
            dest.deleteFile();
        }

        f.move(dest.nativePath);
    }else{
        var dest = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(foldername, filename);
        dest.write(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use events instead of the nested recursion that you are using. Android does not seem to like that too much